# unable to bind address [10048]: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am new to using php web sockets. I am trying to implement simple web sockets but i am getting this error of bind address. I have tried changing the port numbers but its not working in my case. I  am trying this on my local machine.[image]
Code is below

```
    <?php

$host ="localhost";
$port =12345;
set_time_limit(0);
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) or die("Could not create socket \n");
$result_sock = socket_bind($sock,$host,$port)or die("Could not bind to socket \n");
$result_sock = socket_listen($sock,3)or die("Could not Setup socket listener \n");
echo "Listening for connections";


do{

    $accept = socket_accept($sock)or die("Could not accept incoming connection \n");
    $msg = socket_read($accept,1024)or die ("Could not read input \n");

   socket_write($accept,$reply,strlen($reply)) or die ("Could not write input \n");
   $errors = array();
    // connect db
   $db= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','color_luck_db') or die ("Could not connect to  DATABASE");
   $timer_value = "SELECT Timer_Value from gamehistory where Room_Id= '1'";
   $result_timer= mysqli_query($db,$timer_value);
   $_SESSION['timer_value']= $results;
   $result_timer=$result_timer--;

}while($result_timer>0);

socket_close($accept,$sock);
 ?>
```

Comment: This code here is for socket.php file

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and I got solution from this answer by [Jeff Lambert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697370/jeff-lambert)

> "I found [this article](https://support.socketlabs.com/index.php/Knowledgebase/Article/View/61/0/how-to-fix-error-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocolnetwork-addressport-is-normally-permitted) and [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/470766.aspx), each of which are pointing to the possibility that you're either running out of ports or using an invalid port number.
> I don't have too much experience with Windows in this regards, but that second article at least is claiming that you can either use a port in the range 1024-5000, or change a registry setting if you want to go higher. I would try setting your port to something in that range, say 4950, and see if that clears your issue up.
> The registry key in question for any of those interested is `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\MaxUserPort` and the value can go up to 65534. However, I doubt this would be a necessary step, unless you already have ~4000 other processes already running that are using up all of your available ports."

Here is my code:

```php
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $port = 4950;
    set_time_limit(0);
    // create socket
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
    echo "Socket created successfully\n";
    // bind socket
    socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
    echo "socket binding completed\n";
    // lstening on socket
    socket_listen($socket) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
    echo "Listening....";
    while(true){
        //accepting connection of client
        $client = socket_accept($socket) or die("Error in accepting client");
        // saying wellcome to client
        $msg = "welcome";
        socket_write($client, $msg, strlen($msg)) or die("error in ");
    }
?>
```